# Missing snippets in The Rust Programming Language book

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I'm trying to download [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) book in epub format using the [mdbook-epub](https://github.com/Michael-F-Bryan/mdbook-epub/) tool, but the output file doesn't contain any code snippets. Instead it has placeholders like this:

```
{{#include ../listings/ch02-guessing-game-tutorial/listing-02-01/src/main.rs:io}}
```

Some of those placeholders use `rustdoc_include`.

How can I generate a file with the embedded snippets?

Answer (score 1):

I was using a mismatching version of `mdbook`. This solves the problem:

```sh
cargo install mdbook-epub -v 0.3.0
cargo install mdbook --version 0.3.7
```

For completeness, the book can then be generated by editing `book.toml` and adding the `[output.epub]` line at the end. Then `mdbook build` generates the epub file at `book/epub/The Rust Programming Language.epub`.